# Entity Framework and MariaDB - phpMyAdmin

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, mariadb

I'm trying to do a insert in my database following the example at: http://insidemysql.com/howto-starting-with-mysql-ef-core-provider-and-connectornet-7-0-4/. I'm succesful in creating the database and tables, however for some reason I keep getting the same error on the *INSERT* below:

```
var entry = new Sistema();

        using (var context = SistemaFactory.Create(connectionString))
        {
            context.Sistemas.Add(entry);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

This is my model:

```
public class Sistema
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<Agenda> Agendas { get; set; }
}
```

And the error that I keep getting:

```
{Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details. ---> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT `Id`
FROM `Sistemas`
WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1
 AND `Id`=' at line 2
```

As of now I can't fix this error so I'm using PostgreSQL instead of MySQL.

Comment: Show us the SQL that produced the error.

Comment: @RickJames I don't know if its possible, the only SQL that I can get it's already on the question.

Comment: We need to see "line 1".  (Sometimes 3rd party software gets in the way!)

Comment: @RickJames Visual Studio show me only this query: DEFAULT VALUES;
SELECT `Id`
FROM `Sistemas`
WHERE ROW_COUNT() = 1
 AND `Id`=

Comment: @RickJames when I try this query on phpMyAdmin it returns error on "DEFAULT VALUES" line.

Comment: `DEFAULT VALUES;`  -- that sounds like garbage.  Presumably generated from the Framework.

Comment: What database vendor is the Framework configured to generate code for?  `ROW_COUNT()` is not in MySQL or MariaDB.

Comment: @RickJames it's configured to MySQL, don't know if the problem is exclusive to MariaDB... i'll try install the real MySQL and not this version that comes with Xampp.

Comment: @RickJames installed MySQL and still get the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

`DEFAULT_VALUES` and `ROW_COUNT` are found in SQL Server, not MySQL, nor MariaDB.  Your configuration of Entity Framework needs changing.

Answer (score 0):

If you debug the sql statement

```
context.Database.Log = statememnt => Console.WriteLine(statement);
```

or similar, you will probably notice that you try to update a select statement instead of a table.
This is because your table doesn't have a primary key.
Define one and you will be able to update.